Where I need to see the JMeter properties
I'm ready to record a script in JMeter, but in order to import the certification in JMeter, I need to see the JMeter properties. Where do I need to set those JMeter properties?

You don't need to "see" jmeter.properties in order to import the certificate. When you start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder JMeter generates the certificate, the file is called ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt and normally it's being generated under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.
jmeter.properties file is located there as well. If you removed it by accident - you can get one either by downloading JMeter or from JMeter source repository
See How to Configure a HTTP JMeter Proxy Server article for more information
